# How to stretch TabBar items to width of TabBar?

Tags: java, gwt

I want to stretch items of TabBar to width of TabBar itself. I can  make it  using this:

```
.gwt-TabBarItem {
    width: 300px;
}
```

But I want to use here percent values, not pixels (i.e. `width: 100%;`). When I use percents I don't see any effect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with customizing css styles is that we don't understand the big picture. The styles are adjusted by layout/container in response to user actions as well. To identify to actual style, try to debug the UI using firebug/IEdeveloper toolbar. See if the 'style:' attribute is set, if there is no 'style' the chances of achieving desired look and feel using CSS is high.

This what I did when using Ext-GWT. Chances are that you may not fix all the edge cases, but with out proper tools it is very difficult.